# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push'), I'm getting error while using addToCart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, redux, redux-toolkit

```
    import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

    const cartSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'cart',
    initialState: {
    items: [],
    },
    reducers: {
    addToCart: (state, action) => {
      state.items.push(action.payload);
    },
    removeFromCart: (state, action) => {
      state.items = state.items.filter(item => item.id !== action.payload.id);
    },
    clearCart: state => {
      state.items = [];
    },
    },
    });
```

export const { addToCart, removeFromCart, clearCart } = cartSlice.actions;

export default cartSlice.reducer;

It's working while I defined initialstate as array (initialstate =[]) and performing operation (state.push(...)).

Comment: "It's working while I defined initialstate as array (initialstate =[]) and performing operation (state.push(...))." - So the code is working and you don't have any issue? It seems you either (A) don't have any issue to resolve or (B) resolved it yourself already. It's not clear what can be addressed here. If you still need help with something then please [edit] your post to clarify what any specific issue/problem is and include a [mcve] that includes reproduction steps, error message and stacktrace, etc.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I see you meant that when ***state*** is the array, that you can push into it, but with `state.items` you have an issue. Are you using state persistence by any chance? What is the initial state passed to the store? Can you [edit] to include a complete [mcve] how you are instantiating the store?

Comment: @DrewReese yes, I'm using state persistence. Here is my Store.js code-          
   `const rootReducer = combineReducers({
   cart: cartReducer,
    auth: authReducer
    });

    const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage,
    };

    const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

    const store = configureStore(
     {
      reducer : persistedReducer,
      middleware: [thunk]
      }
     );

    const persistor = persistStore(store);
    export { store, persistor };`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

The issue here it seems is that you once had a cart slice the likely looked like the following:

```js
const initialState = [];

const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: "cart",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addToCart: (state, action) => {
      state.push(action.payload);
    },
    removeFromCart: (state, action) => {
      return state.filter((item) => item.id !== action.payload.id);
    },
    clearCart: (state) => {
      return [];
    }
  }
});
```

The state this slice/reducer produced was persisted to localStorage.

Example:

```json
"persist:root": "{"cart":"[{\"id\":\"_DX4ebWHrqY1R6iVevCLV\"},{\"id\":\"JTqqLWDHTyCbk4gSroFYX\"}]","_persist":"{\"version\":-1,\"rehydrated\":true}"}"
```

You then *changed* the cart slice reducers to generate a *different* state shape:

```js
const initialState = {
  items: []
};

const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: "cart",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addToCart: (state, action) => {
      state.items.push(action.payload);
    },
    removeFromCart: (state, action) => {
      state.items = state.items.filter((item) => item.id !== action.payload.id);
    },
    clearCart: (state) => {
      state.items = [];
    }
  }
});
```

But the previous state shape still exists in localStorage and is rehydrated as the state value, and since there is now a mismatch between the current state value and what the reducers/selectors reference this creates the errors.

## Solution(s)

### Reset the saved persisted state

If you don't care or need to save the existing state then you can simply delete the `persist:root` key/value from localStorage and reload the app. Since there will now be no persisted state to hydrate the app state the initial state from the reducers will compute the initial state tree with the current initial state values.

- Open the browser's dev tools
- Navigate to the "Application" tab
- Locate the `localStorage` section
- Delete the `"persist:root"` entry
- Reload the app

[image]

### Migrate the old state to the new state

Create a [migration](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/blob/master/docs/migrations.md) from the old, incorrect, state to the new current state shape.

```js
import { configureStore, combineReducers } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { createMigrate, persistStore, persistReducer } from "redux-persist";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
import cartReducer from "./cart.slice";

const migrations = {
  // Move state.cart to state.cart.items
  0: (state) => {
    const { cart, ...newState } = state;
    return {
      ...newState,
      cart: {
        items: cart
      }
    };
  }
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  cart: cartReducer
  auth: authReducer
});

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage,
  version: 0, // <-- set state version
  migrate: createMigrate(migrations, { debug: true }) // <-- debug true if you want to see logs, otherwise set false
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer
});

const persistor = persistStore(store);

export { store, persistor };
```